# NetInfo react-native , add to AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, react-native

i'm using Netinfo to check the connection on android- react-native and i get that error "To use NetInfo on Android, add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:
"

, although i added it to the file,

Note : i'm using react-native 41

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make sure to restart your packager and then run the Android project again. It sounds like it wasn't built with the new additions.

Comment: when i restart all and build again , the rule i added to the xml file dissapear and error still the same